# bind self signed ssl certificate to port failed

Tags: ssl, https, certificate, windows-10, netsh

I wish to bind a self signed certificate to a port for developing my self hosted wcf application, but I always fail.

Steps I've done:

1. created the root certificate:

   - `makecert.exe -a SHA256 -n "CN=DemoCA" -r -sv TempDemoCA.pvk TempDemoCA.cer`
2. created the client cert:

   - `makecert.exe -a SHA256 -sk Demo -iv TempDemoCA.pvk -n "CN=DemoTempCert" -ic TempDemoCA.cer DemoTemp.cer -sr currentuser -ss My -sky exchange`
3. imported the root cert with mmc.exe(as Administrator) into local computer certificates
4. imported the client cert with mmc.exe into local computer certificates
5. added the private key to the client cert, because it didn't have the key icon:

   - `certutil -repairstore my "MyKeyHash"`
6. Added a firewall entry:

   - `netsh http add urlacl url=https://+:9003/ user=domain\user listen=yes`
7. tried to bind the certificate to the port(as admin):

   - `netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:9003 certhash=MyCertHash appid={NewGuid} clientcertnegotiation=enable`

But step 7 failed with error 1312.

> SSL Certificate add failed, Error 1312
>
> A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.

All I found out by googling, doesn't solve my problem, e.g.:
- import via mmc and not certmgr.msc
- create a new certificate
- KB Hotfix

Interesting fact: binding the existing "localhost" client certificate to a port works fine.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was that the common name has to be the same as the used domain of the service. In my case localhost did the trick.